# How to generate data with a residual from existing data in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 6,000 rows and 10 cols. I want to make this matrix having more than 100,000 rows and 10 cols. I can achieve those result by iterating copy and paste the 6000 rows. However it doesn't satisfy my requirement because it will result in many same duplicated rows in the matrix. Therefore I would like to make the newly generated rows having a residual so that they are little duplicated rows in my matrix. How to achieve my goal? Any help will be appreciated and my matrix looks likes as below.

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V7  V9
2.2220905   2.301025386 0.054225142 4.756829682 0.334153343 600.0109311 50.43052459 0.072883515 0.113307282
2.236265714 2.313014446 0   4.763817419 0   599.8323571 50.48995542 0   0
2.207522656 2.284676693 0   4.757150483 0   598.7919413 50.45089305 0   0
2.229031201 2.352340119 0   4.761297773 0   599.8323571 50.41856725 0   0
2.217272673 2.289254332 0   4.757565228 0   599.653797  50.44810272 0   0
2.186521099 2.271597743 0   4.758754637 0   598.7981781 50.44642817 0   0
2.199993571 2.277265296 0   4.759200658 0   599.4803    50.45172978 0   0
2.198693698 2.276175379 0   4.75262764  0   600.0109311 50.45898435 0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `runif` to add small variations to your data:

```
x <- matrix(1:100,ncol=10)
rbind(x,x+runif(100,min = -1, max = 1))

 [1,]  1.000000 11.0000 21.0000 31.0000 41.0000 51.0000 61.0000 71.0000 81.0000  91.0000
 [2,]  2.000000 12.0000 22.0000 32.0000 42.0000 52.0000 62.0000 72.0000 82.0000  92.0000
 [3,]  3.000000 13.0000 23.0000 33.0000 43.0000 53.0000 63.0000 73.0000 83.0000  93.0000
 [4,]  4.000000 14.0000 24.0000 34.0000 44.0000 54.0000 64.0000 74.0000 84.0000  94.0000
 [5,]  5.000000 15.0000 25.0000 35.0000 45.0000 55.0000 65.0000 75.0000 85.0000  95.0000
 [6,]  6.000000 16.0000 26.0000 36.0000 46.0000 56.0000 66.0000 76.0000 86.0000  96.0000
 [7,]  7.000000 17.0000 27.0000 37.0000 47.0000 57.0000 67.0000 77.0000 87.0000  97.0000
 [8,]  8.000000 18.0000 28.0000 38.0000 48.0000 58.0000 68.0000 78.0000 88.0000  98.0000
 [9,]  9.000000 19.0000 29.0000 39.0000 49.0000 59.0000 69.0000 79.0000 89.0000  99.0000
[10,] 10.000000 20.0000 30.0000 40.0000 50.0000 60.0000 70.0000 80.0000 90.0000 100.0000
[11,]  0.492024 11.5423 20.9987 30.7685 40.2591 51.5929 60.9163 71.5580 80.3786  91.4497
[12,]  1.316443 11.7162 21.0638 32.5324 41.3209 51.9635 61.6196 71.3303 82.0736  91.7983
[13,]  3.076443 12.9613 22.2088 33.1028 43.3016 53.6156 62.8742 73.3251 83.8263  92.8568
[14,]  3.730723 14.6023 24.5809 33.1215 44.9430 53.5754 64.6033 73.7833 84.4959  93.8304
[15,]  4.315171 14.6706 25.5077 35.0501 44.4283 54.8680 65.3649 75.5580 85.9963  95.1450
[16,]  5.206958 16.4521 25.3294 36.8763 46.7809 55.0829 65.8558 76.5779 85.2914  95.7127
[17,]  6.221394 16.7819 27.9710 36.9359 47.0472 57.1599 66.0205 76.9653 86.8937  97.8531
[18,]  7.792519 18.8315 27.3095 37.4447 47.1653 58.4975 68.6369 78.5616 88.4670  97.9888
[19,]  8.680029 19.7073 29.3911 38.9758 49.9359 59.2704 68.8576 78.5707 89.0825  99.4446
[20,] 10.156001 20.0567 29.1127 40.3027 49.2673 59.2314 69.1514 80.8227 90.2210  99.7938
```